# Getting all videos of a Youtube channel

Tags: c#, youtube-api

[This](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ/videos) is an Youtube channel:

I just get playlist of channel but "/UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ/videos" I don't know how to get it?

This is what I've tried:

```
List<ViewModel.YoutubeVideo> arrays = new List<ViewModel.YoutubeVideo>();
        var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Playlists.List("snippet");
        searchListRequest.ChannelId = channelid;
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
        //Call the search.list method to retrieve results...
        var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

        foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
        {
            product = new ViewModel.YoutubeVideo();
            product.id = searchResult.Id;
            product.Name = searchResult.Snippet.Title;
            product.Thumb100Uri = searchResult.Snippet.Thumbnails.Default.Url;
            product.NextPageToken = searchListResponse.NextPageToken;
            product.PreviousPageToken = searchListResponse.PrevPageToken;
            arrays.Add(product);
```

Comment: define get.  Whats wrong with your code as it is?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the videos associated with every playlist in a channel you can use something like this:

```
    var playlistRequest = youtubeService.Playlists.List("id");
    playlistRequest.ChannelId = "UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ";
    playlistRequest.MaxResults = 50;
    var playlistResponse = await playlistRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

to get all the playlists in the channel. And then:

```
    foreach (var playlist in playlistResponse.Items)
    {
        var playlistItemRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
        playlistItemRequest.PlaylistId = playlist.Id;
        playlistItemRequest.MaxResults = 50;
        var videos = await playlistItemRequest.ExecuteAsync();

        foreach (var video in videos.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(video.Snippet.Title);
        }
    }
```

to get all the videos in each playlist.

For the channel that you have specified there are a lot of playlists each with a lot of videos so you will need to modify this to use the page tokens to fetch more than 50 playlists and videos each time.